# Exposed pad and ground

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, ground, pad

I'm using this device - [ATSAMD21G17A](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU32/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/SAM-D21-DA1-Family-Data-Sheet-DS40001882H.pdf)

While I measured the connection between the exposed pad and ground, they seem to be unconnected.

When I went and check on section 10, problem 20, on page 30 of this [Checklist](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/secure/aemDocuments/documents/MCU32/ProductDocuments/DesignChecklist/Basic-32-Bit-MCU-Design-and-Troubleshooting-Checklist-DS70005439.pdf), I found the below:

[image]

Which effectively says us to connected the exposed pad to ground pins of the device and the PCB.

My question:

1. Should the exposed pad of a device always be connected to the ground? If so, why?
   If the exposed pad should always be connected to the ground, then why do manufacturers, in this case, Microchip, do not connect the exposed pad and ground pins of the device together internally?

Like, is the exposed pad solely for thermal dissipation or does it serve as a ground pin as well?

Can the exposed pad be left floating in any case, if I am taking care of thermal dissipation?

Comment: *I measured the connection between the exposed pad and ground, they seem to be unconnected.* Where did you measure it? On a bare chip? On the bare PCB? On the PCBA after the chip was soldered down?...

Comment: Tenting the vias on the *top* side of the exposed pad like in that picture is pretty strange....

Comment: @Hearth, I've seen [similar things](https://i.imgur.com/GVrf6RL.png) recommended in eg. TI's CC2500 datasheet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, the die is made of P-doped silicon, which forms diodes with the N-doped silicon of microelectronic components, so the substrate must have the most negative voltage in the device. Therefore, the substrate is usually connected to ground (or to the negative supply in op-amps).

The exposed pad is connected to the substrate with glue that might be electrically conductive. (The glue is chosen for its mechanical and thermal properties, not for its electrical ones.) So the pad could be left floating, but if it is connected to any voltage, it must be ground. So when you need a large amount of copper for thermal reasons, the ground plane is the obvious choice.

Creating an internal connection between pad and ground would make the packaging more expensive. (The pad is under the die; normal bond wires would not work.)

Other manufacturers like TI [mention some of these considerations in a FAQ](https://e2e.ti.com/support/logic-group/logic/f/logic-forum/723481/faq-where-do-i-connect-the-thermal-pad-of-the-logic-qfn-devices), but it is easier to simply say "connect it to ground".

Answer (score 9):

Read the datasheet for each part. Looking at the datasheet for that part, pg 1058 
*"The exposed die attach pad is not connected electrically inside the device. It is recommenced to attach
(solder) the exposed pad ... to the ground
layer".*

Why the manufacturer doesn't make the connection themselves, is a question for someone who designs these chips. I would assume it's either cheaper or somehow better performance. In this instance where the GND is not internally connected to the pad, but it's recommended, I'd assume this recommendation is either to improve thermal performance or to make routing the GND easier, or just default. You could in this case leave the pad floating, but I can't off hand think of any reason why this would be advantageous.

Most of the time (and I mean like >90%) a thermal pad is to be connected to Ground, sometimes you can leave it floating (like in this case), or others. The manufacturer's datasheet will tell you, and you should always double-check.

It's entirely possible that the manufacturer asks you to connect the pad to Ground, and indeed the design needs you to, without them internally connecting the pins - so don't use measurements to inform your connections.

<strike>PS. I've never seen the vias on an exposed pad covered with solder mask, and I can't imagine that's a good idea!</strike>
P.S. I'm informed by commenters that the solder mask on the exposed pad does get recommended by some manufacturers, but I still don't personally like it. This is, however, beyond the scope of the question, and actually, the manufacturer does recommend either tented or filled vias.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This part's checklist (attached in the question) recommends to connect the exposed pad to the ground pins of the device right?

Comment: I am just curious with the two follow up questions: 1. As you said, in most of the cases, the thermal pad is connected to the ground. In that case, (as with this case too as mentioned in the checklist), why don't the manufacturers don't connect the thermal pad and gnd pins internally by themselves and give it to you? And 2. Is it OK, if I leave the exposed thermal pad floating provided, I take good care of the thermal dissipation of the device?

Comment: Maybe the pad does not extend internally? You normally ground it for EMC reasons as you don’t want an antenna that can radiate. The pad is also for physical attachment.

Comment: @LordTeddy The tented vias leverage the surface tension of solder to prevent all the solder from wicking out into the holes and onto the opposite side of the board.

Comment: About the vias, there is typically also a specified grid pattern in the solder paste to reduce the amount of solder and avoid floating the chip so high that the pins don't wet to their solder pads. Probably the breaks in the solder paste pattern overlap the vias (and the soldermask tents).

Comment: @LordTeddy, I've [seen it recommended](https://i.imgur.com/GVrf6RL.png) in eg. TI's CC2500 datasheet.

Comment: A few edits have been made, including @Newbie's follow up questions

Answer (score 2):

> Like, is the exposed pad solely for thermal dissipation or does it serve as a ground pin as well?

From my experience of using D20.

This isn't a heat sink as such - this is low power MCU, so if it produces a lot of heat, something is very wrong.

My conclusion is that the pad is only there for EMC reasons. So yes it must absolutely be connected to ground. It is fine to do this through multiple vias like in your picture, but you should not have any solder mask there, or it will mess up the assembly.

And it is also wise to route the GND pins of the MCU to this one as well, which you seem to be doing already.

Comment: The via tenting is to prevent the solder from wicking down the non-plugged vias. It's a commonly used technique when lots of vias are present and they are large in diameter relative to the volume of solder available. Large diameter vias (up to a point) have lower impedance. I've had many production boards designed that way and it worked fine, with X-rays looking as intended, with little to no solder pushed into the vias.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica The solder mask will introduce an extra height on which the part will rest. This could mean that the ordinary pins of the QFP end up in the air and the whole part might start "wobbling" during assembly. That's unacceptable and could lead to missing or cold joints. This is a small part so I don't really see a point in spamming so many vias there, nor do they need to be particularly large.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Usually, you tent the vias on the backside of the PCB, not the front where the part gets soldered. That still prevents solder wicking as the trapped air bubbles can't get out, and it doesn't impact assembly at all. It also gives better thermal contact, since the bits of soldermask don't get in the way.

Answer (score 2):

If the manufacturer recommends it, you should do it. 
The pad on some devices/ICs may be:

- only thermally bound to the chip;
- connected to ground;
- connected to any other voltage rail.

It serves not only as a thermal or electric connection, but also to make a stronger mechanical connection/bond to the PCB. 
Another reason is grounding and shielding of high frequencies from the chip - if there were no pad below chip, it could radiate EMI through that side. The pad also absorbs some of the high frequency EM fields from wires/traces above it.

The reasons why there are separate ground pins:

- bonding wires may need to provide the shortest route between chip and PCB without creating a loop
- maybe it was hard to route their bonding wires to the pad.

I would not recommend leaving the pad to float, you should at least provide 1 or 2 vias to the ground plane on your board, even if they don't function as thermal sinks. 
There is a reason manufacturers recommend or instruct circuit or PCB designers to make certain provisions for their products. 
They know what will help their products function better or with fewer problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: It's worth noting that in nearly all cases, the exposed pad is electrically bonded to the backside of the semiconductor die. That backside is usually ground, but on discrete transistors it's nearly always the drain/collector and on SOI chips it's not electrically connected to the rest of the circuit at all. Except in the case of SOI, there's no need for a downbond (what you refer to "route their bonding wires to the pad"), because the die is directly attached to it with solder, conductive epoxy, silver sinter, or whatever die attach method.

Answer (score 1):

Page 1058 of the datasheet states "The exposed die attach pad is not connected electrically inside the device. It is recommenced to attach
(solder) the exposed pad to a matching perimeter landing beneath the package punctuated with vias to the ground
layer". For such a low power MCU, it is not critical, it is there for EMC and mechanical reasons. The above picture of a QFN footprint is problematic - masked vias will cause soldering issues in mass production.
The footprint should use Via in pad, and the vias should not be tented.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Much appreciate it!

Comment: @Lior Bilia, I've [seen it recommended](https://i.imgur.com/GVrf6RL.png) in eg. TI's CC2500 datasheet.

Comment: The CC2500 was a horrible chip with bad performance. The CC2520 is a much better design. Soldermask on the ground pad is a bad idea, it harms the planarity of the pad.